# MVC subdomains using the same cache although they contain different content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, subdomain

I created a website, which uses dynamically created subdomains for different customers, e.g.:
- customer1.mydomain.com
- customer2.mydomain.com

When I open customer1.mydomain.com in one browser and after that customer2.mydomain.com in another browser (or tab), I get cached content of customer1 until I refresh it.

I tried to disable caching in web.config using:

```
<caching>
<outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="NoCache" duration="0" varyByParam="*"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
</outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

I tried to add the following code before class declaration:

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam="host", duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

But nothing seems to work.

Is there any other way to:

- completely disable caching
- or separate cache for each subdomain dynamically

?

Thanks